# how to check whether a hybrid app is executing in background?

Tags: ipad, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an oracle APEX app on ipad as hybrid ipad app built with html5,jquery and uses PhoneGap.

1.Now when I save details on one of the form page->page save process is executing
2.Lock my ipad without waiting to check whether details are saved or not OR goto home and browse through other apps.
3.When i again visit my app,I still see the page as loading.My app freezes.
4.Now I have to close my app and open it newly to check whether details entered are saved or not. This is bit annoying. 
**The details don't get saved.**

What exactly happens to a running app when an ipad is locked OR when we move from running app to any other app?

Can we check if process is getting executed in background?
Can we capture this switch from running app to another OR ipad lock as a jquery/javascript event?

Can we relaunch an app after switch/lock interruption automatically?

Comment: Any clue?? Can we detect lock or app switch event using jquery/javascript?

Comment: Late addition to your question, but background services using non-native apps have always been tricky. There seems to be growing support for this. See this post with various links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210832/can-phonegap-app-work-in-background