# Run cordova/phonegap javascript in background

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, background

We are trying to push a local notication from the background of a cordova app.

We are using the local-notification plugin and have set a timer on a 10 second mark to display the notification.

Now when we try to run our app on android and ios, the app doesn't run in the background. So we start the app, and keep in in the foreground: it receives the notification.

When we press the home (ios) or back (android) it seems like the timers are paused. When we re-open the app it resumes the countdown and displays the notification.

So we were searching and found the following setting:

```
<preference name="keepRunning" value="true" />
```

So we set it in the config.xml but nothing seems to change.

Is there anybody who nows how to run javascript from the background?

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you provide the code, how you schedule the notification?

Comment: also see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210832/can-phonegap-app-work-in-background/23810724