# How to create background service using ionic,angularjs and cordova?

Tags: cordova-plugins

I am working on the project in ionic which have requirement to create background service.
Is there any plugin for the same in cordova?

Comment: hi... what you have done for this?

Answer (score -2):

Please check this somehow related thread

[Can phonegap app work in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210832/can-phonegap-app-work-in-background/23810724#23810724)